# Where to get authorization header to push message in firebase using cURL

Tags: firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to push a message to firebase cloud messaging app using the cURL as mentioned in the docs :

`curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "notification": {
    "title": "FCM Message",
    "body": "This is an FCM Message",
  },
  "token": "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-b5ae1/messages:send HTTP/1.1"`

But I don't understand what would go inside Authorization header. I couldn't find anything in the docs explaining how to get that header without writing any script.

Comment: What's the issue? It seems correct to me on first glance. see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The cURL is indeed correct. I don't understand where to get authorization header. I've written this concern in the question title and the description. I've tried reading the docs  (also specified in the description) to no avail.

Comment: It's a standard protocol for security with http.... you can get the token by reading the api docs (the api you trying to hit)

Comment: I know that but I couldn't find any way to get that token reading the api docs.

Comment: agree with poor documentation by Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to send the notifications using an alternate end-point. The cURL would be something like :

```
curl -X POST \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -H 'authorization: key=AAAATB65iUo:APA91bERs2RboceUoolw_fT8HBPEa5QFNfaMM2vl_GBYeLwhZqmvACz8kS1gCkO0G4m3rFmZgUcy9bgQYm--m0Obo22iTVLtkNkB_85VnqloRP8pVkQC1oEjziKf6AWfeCHzKJFhAIhf' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{ 
    "data":
    {
        "body": "Buzz! Buzz!",
          "vibrate": [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
          "tag": "vibration-sample"
    },
    "notification": {
      "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body": "Great match!",
      "click_action": "https://google.com",
      "icon": "favicon.png",
      "sound": "default"
    },
    "to":"c1fUi9ny450:APA91bEXaOVMUSz_UCLghO5r7hxLH08-Z31pADImU_-o7EhwsXmqdVtWmQ63SU7DigeVD0juTOtx8qE7HUmkMzf7yEj7yw6lYJXtXooR3kIb-CfiAxnaycC0QYyajmlHI0Hx8omOCMCq"
}'
```

Here key would be your server key which can be found from `settings > project settings > Cloud messaging` tab. The `to` key would be generated device token.Also make sure to send notification key in the json to facilitate background notifications. Here `icons` is the name of the icon(in the root of your project) that has to be shown along with the background notification alert and `click_action` is where the browser should take you when the notification alert is clicked upon. Similar is the `sound` key, `default` signifies that the browser should make the default system sound when a notification is received. The notifications can be further customized with additional parameters.

Comment: Can you use that same URL if you're executing this form within an Ionic app using a HTTP Client?